# Why is this layout not looking the way it is supposed to?

Tags: android, layout

I have a little bit issue here. 
layout which i have been designed in photoshop looks like below

[image: pic 1]

and the layout which i design in xml look like below:

[image: pic 2]

So, you see that for some reason, the edittexts look very off.here is the full XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1fed7b">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="114"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/txt_headline" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="281"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="44"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="547"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/txt_subline1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="44"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_hours"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="00"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="2"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="55sp" />
            <TextView
                android:text=":"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/txt_colon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="55sp" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_minutes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="00"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="2"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="55sp" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:text="00"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_seconds"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="189"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="160"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="140"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:text="hh"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:id="@+id/txt_hh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="110"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="140"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:text="mm"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:id="@+id/txt_mm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="160"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="250"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="314"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="314"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_playstore"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_playstore" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="314"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_random"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_random" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="314"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="314"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_facebook"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_fb" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="314"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_start"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_start" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="209"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_skip" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I know, it is a lot of code, but I really need your help here. Can you do me a favor and look through it? That be so awesome!!!

Thank you!

Comment: use ConstraintLayout, it may reduce viewhirercy.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html

Comment: You have used so many linearlayouts which are useless. Please have a look on how to design using linear layout. Then try to develop UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is solution for your problem,copy and past code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1fed7b">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="114"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/txt_headline" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="281"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="44"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="547"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/txt_subline1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="44"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_hours"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:hint="00"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="55sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_colon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=":"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="55sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt_minutes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="00"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="55sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_mm"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="mm"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_hh"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="hh"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_seconds"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="00"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="250"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="314"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="314"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_playstore"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_playstore" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="314"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_random"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_random" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="314"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="314"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_facebook"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_fb" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="314"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_start"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_start" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="209"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_skip" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

hope this will solve your problem